# Unable to configure ssl on mariadb using certbot generated certificates and private key

Tags: ssl, openssl, mariadb, lets-encrypt, certbot

I'm using certbot to generate a certificate for mariadb server and client ,but it's not working.

```
sudo certbot certonly -d mariadbserver -d mariadbuser
```

This is the command that i've used to generate certificates using certbot,
I've got 4 files for both mariadbserver and mariadbuser .
`cert.pem`,`chain.pem`,`fullchain.pem`,`privkey.pem`.

For the above 8 files i've created one certificates folder in `/etc/my.cnf.d/certificates`,First i've copied server files to this folder and renamed it for better understanding similarly did the same thing to client files also.
my folder looks like

```
client-cert.pem client-chain.pem client-fullchain.pem client-privkey.pem server-cert.pem server-chain.pem server-fullchain.pem server-privkey.pem
```

then i executed

```
sudo chown -R mysql. /etc/my.cnf.d/certificates
```

I have added below snippets in server configuration i.e /etc/my.cnf

```
[mariadb]
ssl-ca= /etc/my.cnf.d/certificates/server-chain.pem
ssl-cert= /etc/my.cnf.d/certificates/server-cert.pem
ssl-key= /etc/my.cnf.d/certificates/server-privkey.pem

[client-mariadb]
ssl-ca= /etc/my.cnf.d/certificates/client-chain.pem
ssl-cert= /etc/my.cnf.d/certificates/client-cert.pem
ssl-key= /etc/my.cnf.d/certificates/client-privkey.pem
```

Then i've restarted mariadb server using `sudo service mariadb restart`.But after doing this when i login to mariadb, cipher is showing not in use. what should i do? am i doing anything wrong in the above steps.

Comment: Why do you need client certificates? Why do you specify chain as server certificate?

Comment: Hi @GeorgRichter, i am trying to configure two way ssl connection so that's why i have added both client and server ssl configuration.